# How to recompile a single .cc file in a project built previously with CMake tool in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-odometry

I am using the ORB_SLAM3 project (https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3) as a baseline for a monocular odometry system.

To understand how the ORB_SLAM3 software ingests the EuRoCV dataset, I am modifying some of the initial codes in the mono_euroc.cc file available in /Examples/Monocular folder.

However, each time I change the .cc file, I cannot compile just the mono_euroc.cc file by itself, but need to run the ./build.sh command from the parent directory which executes the entire CMake. The process which takes a while to complete.

My question is, is there a tool within CMake that would allow me to only change the "mono_euroc.cc" file directly from the "/Examples/Monocular" subdirectory rather than having to constantly invoke the "./build.sh" from the parent directory?

Comment: I don't know what `build.sh` does exactly. If it's working like a similarly named script in some repository I work with, this could completely clear all build results, reconfigure the cmake project, build it, run cpack, copy the results and delete the build dir afterwards. If this is the case, I strongly recommend changing the workflow for purposes other than building a release version. Basically once you've got the cmake project configured in a directory `x`, you can build it using`cmake --build x`(possibly passing`--config ..`too) If cmake doesn't pick up on the change,simply `touch` the .cc

Comment: The solution is likely in the steps between build.sh and cmake. Cmake itself doesn't do any building. It generates build files (makefiles, ninja files, VS Solutions, etc.) and has the ability to invoke the build system it just configured. The answer to your question is in the build system cmake created. Reading and understanding build.sh will likely be helpful.

Comment: A possibility might be to change the build to use [ccache](https://ccache.dev/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I am following this process. I opened two terminal windows, both pointing to the parent directory (i.e ~/Dev/ORB_SLAM3). Everytime I change something in the target file (here it is the ./Examples/Monocular/euroc_mono) I execture the ./build.sh command in one and run the file on the other. I can confirm that though the cmake command looks over all the files, it only builds the one that was changed. I guess this method works when one is using the CMake tool to build a C++ project in Linux.